# A question on the Reiter method

Tags: numerical-methods

I am confused about how individual decision rules are approximated via the Reiter method. In particular, on page 653 of Reiter (2009) (JEDC),  the link is:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165188908001528

The decision rule $K = (x;\Omega_t)$ is represented by a vector $s_t$ which consists of knot points {$x_{t,i}$}. It seems to me that the method is approximating only along the idiosyncratic dimension, so this vector $s_t$ is different for different aggregate states $\Omega_t$. But then why is this useful when the Euler equation has both $s_t$ and $s_{t-1}$?

Comment: It just occurred to me that indeed we just need to write everything in the form of f($X_t$, $X_{t-1}$, expectation errors, $\epsilon_t$) = 0. We are basically turning value functions $V_t$ and $V_{t-1}$ into vectors so that they can be put in to this form. We do not need to use VFI to solve for how $V$ depends on aggregate states, the purturbation step takes care of that. If I am mistaken please correct me.